# fit method in sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Which optimization algorithm the `fit` method of `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` uses for parameter estimation of regression model?

How are the weights of the regression model derived? Is it by using GD or SGD or something else?

Comment: It uses Ordinary Least Squares, according to the "gelsd" Lapack routine. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521115 for more information

Comment: Yeah as @Uvar saud it is plain OLS method. Check the source [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L417). Line : 469-470

Comment: Its also mentioned on the [sklearn documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn-linear-model-linearregression) in the Note part just below attributes.